# Check for Duplicates in Tableau using calculation field or other alternatives

Tags: sql, duplicates, tableau-api, calculated-columns

I am trying to build a logic to identify a duplicate value in my data. The data has many 4 columns SR number, Sales order, item number, and value.

The 1st column (SR number) is always going to be a unique number - primary key. 
The logic I am looking at is: if the Sr number has the **same** sales order, item number, and the value then its a duplicate, give me a yes in front of the row.

Sample data :

```
SR Number   Sales order   Item no   Amount
------------------------------------------
  1001      A201            100     $5,000 
  1002      B403            200        $25 
  1003      B403            300        $25 
  1004      C303            100     $5,000 
  1005      C303            300        $25 
  1006      A201            100     $5,000 
  1007      A201            100     $5,000 
  1008      D707            500       $230 
  1009      C303            300        $25 
  1010      D707            500       $230
```

Expected results:

```
SR Number   Saler order Item no Amount  Duplicate
1001    A201    100 $5,000  Yes
1002    B403    200 $25     No
1003    B403    300 $25     No
1004    C303    100 $5,000  No
1005    C303    300 $25     Yes
1006    A201    100 $5,000  Yes
1007    A201    100 $5,000  Yes
1008    D707    500 $230    Yes
1009    C303    300 $25     Yes
1010    D707    500 $230    Yes
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the underlying database.

Answer (score 2):

This is tagged SQL, so I'll give a SQL solution:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by sr_number, sale_order) > 1
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as duplicate_flag
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, my query is kind of complicated with a lot of joins and all these columns coming from different tables. I will try to incorporate this in the query level. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need this done in Tableau, you can use a Level of Detail calculation. Concatenate the three fields into one string and then count how many times they appear across the data set.

```
if {fixed [Sales Order]+str([Item Number])+str([Amount]): count([Number of Records])}>1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you Bernardo. This works for me!! Right now i will just use this. :)